# Page gets reloaded on CSV download in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

On click of a button, CSV file should get downloaded. I have used below Javascript code for same.
JS:

```
functionName(){
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
anchorTag.href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(csvStringResult); //csv processed data
anchorTag.target="_self";
anchorTag.download="file name.csv";
anchorTag.innerHTML = "link text";
document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
anchorTag.click();
}
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-button variant="destructive" icon-name="utility:download" label="Download" class="slds-m-left_x-small" title="Download"
                onclick={functionName}></lightning-button>
```

But when I click the button for 1st time, the page gets reloaded.
When I click the button for the second time, the file gets downloaded and the page is not reloaded.

I tried setting `anchorTag.href="test.com";`. Blank file gets downloaded but still page is reloaded.  When I comment `anchorTag.download="file name.csv";` in this case page is not reloaded.

There are 3 buttons on the page doing the same function.

How should I prevent it from reloading for 1st time while downloading the file?

Answer (score 1):

Though the same code works for me https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/05/export-data-as-csv-file-with-javascript.html , but it depends on your template.

Try to add attribute as `type="button"`, `defaults to button` which will tell the browser that its a button and don't treat it as a form.

Or else try to `return false` at the end of the function.

May be you might be having this inside a form and the button might be acting as a `submit` action.

Comment: I tried adding anchorTag.type="button";. but still the same issue. Also, I have not used the form.

Comment: did you try returning false, or try `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` also can you paste the full html code, so as to replicate the issue , as its not replicable in my org.

Comment: @Ajinkyasd Nagendra is correct. you should start your function off as `functionName(event) { event.preventDefault();` then create the link. There's no need to add it to the body, either, the browser should automatically download the file when you `click()` the anchor tag.

Comment: @sfdcfox/nagendra I tried both the solutions but didnt work. still page gets reloaded. code: functionName(event){
//above code.. in description
//event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.preventDefault();
}

Comment: That's odd, can you try to do the same thing in playground https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground, and pass the playground link if its replicable.

Comment: I tried on playground but its not replicable there. I there are 4 buttons on same page calling same function. Will it cause this reload issue?

Comment: I dont think that would have any effect and wont trigger refresh until its specified. Can you share the full template and function as the funtion and snippet provided by you does not trigger page reload.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to share the complete code due to security policy.